# How can i disable clear and wipe session data on logout woccomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

i am having problem about the tweak that woocommerce added from version 2.2.0 - 10/09/2014.
In this update, clear and wipe session data on logout woccomerce it happends by default.
I do not want to happend this into my website, i want when costumer logs in to save data. For example if costumer add items to cart then logout. I want him to have items in cart after singed in again.
How can i disable this tweak !!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the `WC_Session_Handler` class in `includes/wc-session-handler.php` I think I have traced this to the `destroy_session` method that is run on the `clear_auth_cookie` hook. Therefore, to disable it you'd want to remove this method from that hook.

Keep in mind, this is totally untested, so use at your own risk:

```
function so_26720687_keep_session_on_logout(){
    remove_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', array( WC()->session, 'destroy_session' ) );
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'so_26720687_keep_session_on_logout' );
```

Comment: where to add this code ? i tried in functions.php but nothing is happening !!

Comment: Like I said, it is just a guess. But I think it needs to be in a plugin? Maybe even an `mu-function`. I think the `woocommerce_loaded` hook has already fired by the time functions.php is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking to solve this, add the following to your themes functions.php file. This will keep current sessions including active carts when logging out.

```
function present_keep_sessions_on_logout(){
    remove_action( 'wp_logout', array( WC()->session, 'destroy_session' ) );
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'present_keep_sessions_on_logout' );
```